# How to set maximum xmx and xms values without outofmemory exception

Tags: java, jvm

I am trying to run some .jar file but I am getting below error. The system has 20 gb of ram and my Xms and Xmx values are -Xms2048m -Xmx4096m

Are these values are too big or there is another thing causing this error?

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

**EDIT:**

```
java -jar -Xms2048m -Xmx4096m /Filereadertest.jar
```

I am using java 1.7.51

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM

Comment: What version of the VM are you running? Can you include the exact command you are trying to execute as well as the output from `java -version`?

Comment: Are you by chance running the 32-bit version of Java? Seeing the exact full output of `java -version` would tell us this.

Comment: @Todd no its 64 bit vm server.

Comment: OOM suggests that runtime ran out of memory, unless this JAR is allocating memory indefinitely, it just needs more memory. Keep adding to it, if you suspect that this JAR should not be using this much memory then you'll have to debug the root cause.

Comment: Did you analyse heap dumps using heap analyzer? If not I would suggest you to analyse heap dumps which would tell you which part of the code is causing OOM .

Answer (score 2):

> Are these values are too big or there is another thing causing this error?

The default for the server JVM is 1/4 of main memory or 5 GB, so you are actually *decreasing* the maximum by setting this.

You could set it to 80% of main memory such as `-Xmx16G`

Answer (score 0):

Along with JRE version and architecture, heap space per process also depends upon the operating system in use.

For example, Windows 32-bit allows maximum 2 GB memory per process, which also includes size for stacks, libraries and other stuff. So in practice, we generally get 1.25 GB memory.

Have a look at:
[Oracle's Guidelines for Heap Space Sizing](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3681/abeii/index.html)